# struggling to place labels of totals on top of a bar chart in R with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-text

I am having trouble plotting using geom_text to put the values of the totals on top of my bar chart, as it puts every value on it (the value the variable takes for each "specialite") [here is the bar plot i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJc1m.png).
I would like to plot only the total of each bar, a little above each bar (the bars do not all have the same height so the labels should not all be at the same height too).

Here is my current code :

```
NCN_1 %>% 
  filter(type_de_sejour == "Ambulatoires") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("nb_sejours_N","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N2"), values_to = 
"visit") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, y=visit, x=name)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  ggtitle("Evolution du nombre de séjours en ambulatoire") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 5),
        legend.title = NULL,
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y= "nombre de séjours",
       fill = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = as.numeric(visit), label = format(visit, digits = 1)),
            size = 2.5,
            position = position_dodge(.9),
            inherit.aes = TRUE,
            na.rm = TRUE)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("nb_sejours_N2" = "2019", "nb_sejours_N1" = "2020",
                            "nb_sejours_N" = "2021"), 
limits=c("nb_sejours_N2","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N"))
```

Here is the structure of my dataset, for reproducibility :

```
 structure(list(type_de_sejour = c("Ambulatoires", "Hospitalisé", 
 "Hospitalisé", "Ambulatoires", "Hospitalisé", "Séances"), 
    specialite = c("ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", "ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", 
    "Autres", "CARDIO VASCULAIRE", "CARDIO VASCULAIRE", "CARDIO VASCULAIRE"
     ), CA_annee_N = c(2712L, 122180L, 0L, 822615L, 6905494L, 
     0L), nb_sejours_N = c(8L, 32L, 0L, 1052L, 2776L, 0L), nb_praticiens_N = c(5L, 
    8L, 0L, 12L, 15L, 0L), CA_annee_N1 = c(4231L, 78858L, 6587L, 
    327441L, 6413083L, 0L), nb_sejours_N1 = c(13L, 29L, 2L, 532L, 
    2819L, 0L), nb_praticiens_N1 = c(6L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 0L
    ), CA_annee_N2 = c(4551L, 27432L, 0L, 208326L, 7465440L, 
    575L), nb_sejours_N2 = c(15L, 8L, 0L, 463L, 3393L, 1L), nb_praticiens_N2 = c(6L, 
    4L, 0L, 11L, 13L, 1L), site = c("FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", 
    "FRA", "FRA"), activite_en_volume_N = c(8L, 32L, 0L, 1052L, 
    2776L, 0L), activite_en_volume_N1 = c(13L, 29L, 2L, 532L, 
    2819L, 0L), activite_en_volume_N2 = c(15L, 8L, 0L, 463L, 
    3393L, 1L), proportion_N = c(0.00059475131960449, 0.00237900527841796, 
    0, 0.0782097985279905, 0.206378707902758, 0), proportion_N1 = c(0.00107794361525705, 
    0.00240464344941957, 0.000165837479270315, 0.0441127694859038, 
    0.233747927031509, 0), proportion_N2 = c(0.000977517106549365, 
    0.000521342456826328, 0, 0.0301726946888237, 0.221114369501466, 
    6.5167807103291e-05)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    site = "FRA", .rows = structure(list(1:6), ptype = integer(0), class = 
 c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), .drop = TRUE))
```

[EDIT] : after receiving 2 answers, I tried this code :

```
NCN_1 %>% 
   filter(type_de_sejour == "Ambulatoires") %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = 
 c("nb_sejours_N","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N2"), values_to = 
                 "visit") %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(total = sum(visit)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(fill=name, y=visit, x=name)) + 
   geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
   facet_wrap(~site) +
   ggtitle("Evolution du nombre de séjours en ambulatoire") +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 
 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 
5),
        legend.title = NULL,
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y= "nombre de séjours",
       fill = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = as.numeric(total), label = 
format(total, digits = 1)),
           size = 2.5,
           position = position_dodge(1),
           inherit.aes = TRUE,
           na.rm = TRUE, vjust = 1)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("nb_sejours_N2" = "2019", 
"nb_sejours_N1" = "2020",
                           "nb_sejours_N" = "2021"), 
               
limits=c("nb_sejours_N2","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N"))
```

But the problem is, as I facet, the bars on one facet being lower than the bars on the other, the labels are adapted to one facet and not the other. How could I solve this problem ?

[here is my new plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffaY.png)

[EDIT 2] : Here is a better dataset to reproduce my example :

```
structure(list(type_de_sejour = c("Ambulatoires", "Hospitalisé", 
"Hospitalisé", "Ambulatoires", "Hospitalisé", "Séances", 
"Ambulatoires", 
"Hospitalisé", "Ambulatoires", "Externes", "Hospitalisé", 
"Ambulatoires", 
"Hospitalisé"), specialite = c("ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", 
"ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", 
"Autres", "CARDIO VASCULAIRE", "CARDIO VASCULAIRE", "CARDIO 
VASCULAIRE", 
"CHIRUGIE CARDIAQUE", "CHIRUGIE CARDIAQUE", "ANESTHESIE 
REANIMATION", 
"ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", "ANESTHESIE REANIMATION", "Autres", 
"Autres"), CA_annee_N = c(2712L, 122180L, 0L, 822615L, 6905494L, 
0L, 78064L, 2483804L, 64310L, 0L, 265255L, 25298L, 3061L), 
nb_sejours_N = c(8L, 
32L, 0L, 1052L, 2776L, 0L, 129L, 388L, 171L, 0L, 280L, 34L, 3L
), nb_praticiens_N = c(5L, 8L, 0L, 12L, 15L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 
0L, 12L, 3L, 3L), CA_annee_N1 = c(4231L, 78858L, 6587L, 327441L, 
6413083L, 0L, 96453L, 3527754L, 50135L, 0L, 65145L, 454L, 4076L
), nb_sejours_N1 = c(13L, 29L, 2L, 532L, 2819L, 0L, 158L, 570L, 
150L, 1L, 41L, 1L, 4L), nb_praticiens_N1 = c(6L, 9L, 1L, 12L, 
12L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L), CA_annee_N2 = c(4551L, 
27432L, 0L, 208326L, 7465440L, 575L, 135733L, 4745148L, 48583L, 
0L, 33388L, 453L, 507L), nb_sejours_N2 = c(15L, 8L, 0L, 463L, 
3393L, 1L, 236L, 835L, 154L, 3L, 26L, 1L, 1L), nb_praticiens_N2 = 
c(6L, 
4L, 0L, 11L, 13L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L), site = c("FRA", 
"FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "PGS", "PGS", 
"PGS", "PGS", "PGS"), activite_en_volume_N = c(8L, 32L, 0L, 1052L, 
2776L, 0L, 129L, 388L, 171L, 0L, 280L, 34L, 3L), 
activite_en_volume_N1 = c(13L, 
29L, 2L, 532L, 2819L, 0L, 158L, 570L, 150L, 1L, 41L, 1L, 4L), 
    activite_en_volume_N2 = c(15L, 8L, 0L, 463L, 3393L, 1L, 236L, 
    835L, 154L, 3L, 26L, 1L, 1L), proportion_N = 
c(0.00059475131960449, 
    0.00237900527841796, 0, 0.0782097985279905, 0.206378707902758, 
    0, 0.00959036502862241, 0.0288454390008178, 
0.00589147286821705, 
    0, 0.00964685615848406, 0.00117140396210164, 
0.000103359173126615
    ), proportion_N1 = c(0.00107794361525705, 0.00240464344941957, 
    0.000165837479270315, 0.0441127694859038, 0.233747927031509, 
    0, 0.0131011608623549, 0.0472636815920398, 0.00571689915389892, 
    3.81126610259928e-05, 0.00156261910206571, 3.81126610259928e- 
05, 
    0.000152450644103971), proportion_N2 = c(0.000977517106549365, 
    0.000521342456826328, 0, 0.0301726946888237, 0.221114369501466, 
    6.5167807103291e-05, 0.0153796024763767, 0.054415118931248, 
    0.00479153702551338, 9.33416303671438e-05, 
0.000808960796515246, 
    3.11138767890479e-05, 3.11138767890479e-05)), class = 
c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), groups = 
structure(list(
    site = c("FRA", "PGS"), .rows = structure(list(1:8, 9:13), 
ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: You noted that there are different values for each specialite. Are you trying to plot the total across both values of this variable or the values for each level of it? If the former, Quinten's answer is appropriate and you didn't pass an object with the appropriate variables to `ggplot()`. If the latter, you need to assign specialite to an aesthetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you computed your `total` value for the whole dataset instead of per site, i.e. `group_by` `name` and `site`. Also, IMHO you could simplify by summarising your dataset for plotting which also avoids the duplicated labels (note the bold-ish look of the labels which stems from overplotting). Also, instead of using `vjust` you could use `nudge_y` to shift the labels (which requires to drop the unnecessary `position_dodge`).

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- NCN_1 %>%
  filter(type_de_sejour == "Ambulatoires") %>%
  pivot_longer(c("nb_sejours_N", "nb_sejours_N1", "nb_sejours_N2"), values_to = "visit") %>%
  group_by(name, site) %>%
  summarise(visit = sum(visit))

ggplot(dat, aes(fill = name, y = visit, x = name)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  ggtitle("Evolution du nombre de séjours en ambulatoire") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 8),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 5),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7)
  ) +
  labs(
    x = NULL,
    y = "nombre de séjours",
    fill = NULL
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = visit, label = format(visit, digits = 1)),
    size = 2.5, inherit.aes = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE, vjust = 0, nudge_y = 10
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels = c(
      "nb_sejours_N2" = "2019",
      "nb_sejours_N1" = "2020",
      "nb_sejours_N" = "2021"
    ),
    limits = c("nb_sejours_N2", "nb_sejours_N1", "nb_sejours_N")
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add a column per group with the sum of your visit column and use that as your label. With `vjust` you can adjust the position of the label like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
NCN_1 %>% 
  filter(type_de_sejour == "Ambulatoires") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("nb_sejours_N","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N2"), values_to = 
                 "visit") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(visit)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, y=visit, x=name)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  ggtitle("Evolution du nombre de séjours en ambulatoire") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 5),
        legend.title = NULL,
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y= "nombre de séjours",
       fill = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = as.numeric(total), label = format(total, digits = 1)),
            size = 2.5,
            position = position_dodge(.9),
            inherit.aes = TRUE,
            na.rm = TRUE, vjust = -1)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("nb_sejours_N2" = "2019", "nb_sejours_N1" = "2020",
                            "nb_sejours_N" = "2021"), 
                   limits=c("nb_sejours_N2","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though i still have a problem : when i facet, the 2 plots i get have different height of bars, and the labels are displayed in the same way in the 2 plots (whereas one has bars that are way less high...). I have edited my post to add the new plot I get in order for you to see my issue

Comment: @gérard, could you please share some more data? Now we only have one categorical variable of your facet.

Comment: yes, i'll edit !

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the labels with respect to the bars can be achieved with `vjust`.

However, the main issue is that you have two rows in your `data.frame` for each combination of the x and y variables. This means that `ggplot` is essentially plotting two objects directly on top of each other. This is why you see two numbers per column in your figure.

You note that you actually want to distingush between each "specialite," but this variable doesn't actually appear in your `ggplot()` call. You can fix this problem by explicitly adding an aesthetic for "specialite" so that there is only one row per aesthetic combination.

Doing this with a stacked bar chart looks pretty horrible since the y-axis values in one group greatly exceeds that of the other. Accordingly, you can dodge the bars to place them side-by-side. This also will fix the labeling issue.

To demonstrate all of this, let's use a simplified example of your plot with your data:

```r
# Packages
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr
library(ggplot2)

# Pre-process your data using your code
NCN_1 <- NCN_1 %>%
  filter(type_de_sejour == "Ambulatoires") %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c("nb_sejours_N", "nb_sejours_N1", "nb_sejours_N2"),
    values_to =
      "visit"
  )

# Create a simpler figure that reproduces the problem
NCN_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = visit, label = visit)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text()
```

[image]

Let's now put the labels at the end and use separate bars for each specialite:

```r
# Putting the bars side-by-side
NCN_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = visit, label = visit, fill = specialite)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.2)
```

[image]

We could continue to stack the bars like you did, but as you can see in the bwlo, stacking the bars doesn't look very good:

```r
NCN_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = visit, label = visit, fill = specialite)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.7)
```

[image]

Now that I've shown this, let's apply the logic in the side-by-side plot to your figure while adjusting the location of the labels:

```r
NCN_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=specialite, y=visit, x=name)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~site) +
  ggtitle("Evolution du nombre de séjours en ambulatoire") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1, size = 8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5, size = 5),
        legend.title = NULL,
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 7)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y= "nombre de séjours",
       fill = NULL) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = as.numeric(visit), label = format(visit, digits = 1)),
            size = 2.5,
            position = position_dodge(1),
            vjust = -1,
            inherit.aes = TRUE,
            na.rm = TRUE)+
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("nb_sejours_N2" = "2019", "nb_sejours_N1" = "2020",
                            "nb_sejours_N" = "2021"), 
                   limits=c("nb_sejours_N2","nb_sejours_N1","nb_sejours_N"))
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that when i facet, the 2 plots i get have different height of bars, and the labels are displayed in the same way in the 2 plots (whereas one has bars that are way less high...). I have edited my post to add the new plot I get.

Comment: This is an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/ Please do not change the question to a different question but rather post a separate one if your initial question was answered even if in answering your initial question an unexpected result emerged. One question per post, thanks.